# Virtualbox "Installation Type"

Tags: virtualbox

So I'm setupping Ubuntu on my vm on Virtualbox and I'm in the `Installation type`.

I think im going to select the following option:
`Erase disk and install Ubuntu`
and it says that it deletes all programs, documents in all my os's including my w10, but it

> This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?

I'm just confirming that it doesnt affect my w10 hard drives, since I created my virtual hard drive etc.

I've never used a virtual machine ever before, so I'm just checking & confirming that its safe to use that option :/

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/768906/ubuntu-installation-to-vm-write-the-changes-to-disks

Answer (score 6):

On your virtual machine, there's no operating system installed, so it is perfectly correct to select erasing option.