# During Ubuntu Installation to VM, should I "write the changes to disks"?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in a virtual machine. I click **Erase disk and install Ubuntu** and click <kbd>install now</kbd>.

Then a dialog pops up which reads the following:

> Write the changes to disks?
>
> If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disk. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually.
>
> The partition tables of the following devices are changed:
>
> SCSI3 (0,0,0,) (sda)
>
> The following partitions are going to be formatted:
>
> partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4
>
> partition #5 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) as swap

I believe that that's just a message confirming that I'm going to erase and delete all my files? But there's nothing to delete on my virtual hard drive, since there's nothing in there, but

> This computer currently has no detected operating systems.

Maybe I'll just click continue? I have no idea what I should do, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/768886/virtualbox-installation-type

Answer (score 6):

If you're installing Ubuntu within a new virtual machine, then it's going to be installed to a virtual disk, and yes, it's perfectly safe to click <kbd>continue</kbd>. Enjoy your new virtual Ubuntu installation!